# How to hide content for forms based authenticated user

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, forms-authentication

I have one requirement like I want to hide the data (lists/libraries/documents)  to the users which are forms based authenticated. Windows users can add the data into sharepoint lists. Forms based authenticated users only able to see when ever windows authenticated users give the permission. I thought to create one group for the forms based authentication, but we cannot hide data from them, so this will not work. How to do this ? I am thinking on this, but not able to find the solution. 
Any one has any idea?

**New Addition:**

Actually, there should be two urls (say URL1, URL2) for the same site which we can configure in the alternate access mapping. Only one url (URL2) should be exposed to external users. So, when ever any external user login(Forms user) then we have to show the content which is given access by windows authenticated user. Means when windows users add some content to the URL1 and the give permission for the form authentication users then that content should appear in URL2. By default the content added in the URL1 will be reflected to URL2. But here it should not happen.

Comment: instead of creating a group with FBA users, create a group for internal users, and grant permissions (or audiences) only to this external group.

Comment: @Steve But to identify the forms users, should we write any code to add them into a particular group?

Comment: Mihir, as SharePoint authentication mechanism only supports GRANT and not DENY, you have to find a way to identify users to which you want to GRANT access. If you don't want FBA users to have access to something, you don't have to grant access to it. So you have to GRANT access to others users, using whatever group you want.

Comment: Please see my edited question once

Answer (score 0):

Principally, there shouldn't be a problem duplicating your site, and modifying the copy to be more limited than the original.

If both sites are on the same site collection, you can configure them to use the same lists/document libraries.

After you do that, it's simply a matter of configuring AAM to present one site outside, and one inside.